# User must log in again after restarting app (WebView, Android). How to fix? [SOLVED]

Tags: android, authentication, cookies, android-webview

I'm writing android app with WebView. Everything works well except saving user authentication. If I restart my app, I must log in on the site again. It's not a good behaivor.

I tried to fix it using cookies, but my code has no effect. I also added two permissions in AndroidManifest: INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE. What I did wrong and how I can fix this problem?

My code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String url = "https://drive2.ru/";        

        configWebView(url);

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
            webView.loadUrl(url);

    }
```

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private void configWebView(String url) {

        WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);        
        webViewSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webViewSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webViewSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webViewSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webViewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webViewSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        configCookies(url);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(url);
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("cookie", cookie).apply();
                     
            }

        });

    }
```

```
private void configCookies(String url) {

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);

        String cookie = sharedPreferences.getString("cookie", "none");
        
        if (!cookie.equals("none")){

            cookieManager.setCookie(url, s);
       
        }

    }
```

With this code, when the user restarts the app he has fully identical cookies as before closing the app. But, in fact, logging in on the site is not done.

UPD: I find there was a problem. It's because a site that I tried to open used redirects to different mirrors. Without redirecting everything works well :)